# Twilio Client Call Routing

Tags: twilio

Looking over the Twilio Client setup am I correct in thinking that for each person I want to route a call to that I need to have a TwiML app set up for that person.

That way they each have a unique name to register with to accept inbound calls. Then I am also limited to only haveing 1,000 apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should only need to have a single TwiML App, but you can dynamically generate the TwiML returned from that apps Voice Request URL with whatever client name you are trying to reach.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect. I was just thinking about how to use it wrong.